# Adding a list of lists in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame like this

```
A  B   C 
0  1   2
1  6   5
```

I need to add a list of lists in the 4th column of the dataframe . So that it becomes

```
A  B   C   D
0  1   2   [[4,-0.05],[0.03,[-0.02,0.02]],[0.01,-0.03]]
1  6   5   [[4,-0.35],[0.07,[-0.02,0.02]],[0.91,-0.03]]
```

Please note the list of lists in column D. I am unable to find a way to add this type of column data to pandas dataframe

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create new Series as

```
In [11]: df['D'] = pd.Series([[[4,-0.05],[0.03,[-0.02,0.02]],[0.01,-0.03]],
                              [[4,-0.35],[0.07,[-0.02,0.02]],[0.91,-0.03]]])
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B  C                                                  D
0  0  1  2  [[4, -0.05], [0.03, [-0.02, 0.02]], [0.01, -0....
1  1  6  5  [[4, -0.35], [0.07, [-0.02, 0.02]], [0.91, -0....
```

However, I'm not sure, why you would want to store data in this structure!

Comment: Thanks a lot John. I am using this structure to store the outcomes of a optimization problem. Column A,B,C are values of various performance measures calculated by  the optimization parameters in column D. Column D is predetermined. Appreciate any suggestions on efficient data structure for this kind of problem.